# imbalanced experiment group design

Tags: anova, experiment-design

I am trying to decide if I can use an univariate GLM model in SPSS with factors of  cause, side and tool with the sample size distribution as below. Ideally, tool should be added as a random factor but when I do that, the output has a lot of blank spots. TIA.

Edits for the study design:
The study design is super-imbalanced. The data is from amputees so it's not easy to enroll. The "tool" variable is the prosthesis they use. I cannot figure out how to determine how to test if the cause, side and tool/prosthesis affects their response variable (function). I think have the following options: first analysis to see the effect of cause, if not significant then I am OK with pooling at least two of the causes (2 and 3) so then I will have two main cause groups. Then run another analysis within the collapsed cause group for the effect of side and tool/prosthesis. I can also include only the cases with more common tools/prosthesis (tool 2 and 3). I would not be able to determine the effect of side or tool/prosthesis in cause 1 subjects due to low sample size. Does this line of thinking look OK? Thank you again!

[image: sample distribution by cause, side and tools used]

Answer (score 1):

A big problem is that you only have 1 observation for each of `tool4` and `tool5`, those were both used only under `cause3`, with `tool5` only used on `side1` and `tool4` on `side2`. Also, `tool1` only seems to have been used on `side2`. And `cause1,side1` only was handled once, with `tool6`. That limits your ability to disentangle those `tools` from those particular sets of conditions.

Without more information about the nature of the study and what led to the major differences in the various `tool` values, it's hard to see how to proceed reliably. If the outcome variable is itself the choice of tool under combinations of `side` and `cause`--that is, the outcome is the set of numbers within the cells of your table--there might be some solution, but the small number of overall cases (fewer than 40, by a quick count) indicates that you will have trouble in any event.

*Added in response to edited question*

The problem with proceeding as you propose:

> first analysis to see the effect of cause, if not significant then I am OK with pooling at least two of the causes (2 and 3) so then I will have two main cause groups. Then run another analysis within the collapsed cause group for the effect of side and tool/prosthesis.

is that you are using the results of the study to determine how to analyze the study. That's not generally good practice. At best, the p values that you get at later steps will be unreliable as they are based on an assumption that tests were pre-specified without seeing the results. See for example Chapter 4 of [Frank Harrell's course notes](http://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) for guidance on multiple-variable modeling.

It's best to think through carefully just what hypotheses you can reasonably hope to test with fewer than 40 observations. In a biomedical study that's usually only enough to handle about 3 predictors when there's a continuous outcome (10-20 cases per predictor). Your `cause` with 3 levels already counts as 2 predictors; `side` by itself is another, and if you include interactions with `cause` that's 2 more. Even as a random effect, `tool` is at least 1 beyond that.

So: Do you care more about the association of function with `side` or with `cause` or with `tool`? Does your knowledge of the subject matter suggest that 2 types of `cause` would have similar effects, or that you might reasonably combine some types of `tool`? Maybe you could even just combine all `tool` types together at this stage of your study?

An alternative to avoid overfitting this limited data set would be to use a penalized approach like ridge regression, particularly if you could combine data across some or all the levels of `tool`. The imbalance in the data set could still pose difficulties for interpretation, however.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. It is super-imbalanced. The data is from amputees so it's not easy to enroll. The "tool" variable is the prosthesis they use. I cannot figure out how to determine how to test if the cause, side and tool/prosthesis affects their response variable (function). I think have the following options:

Comment: @PhDDhP for the benefit of others who view your question and might have an answer, please provide that information about the study by editing the initial question. Comments are easy to overlook and can sometimes get deleted.

Comment: and not to mention the character limit. I just edited my post. Thanks much!